# Is there a certain word to shorten this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> "I consume less sugar and salty foods *but consume more fatty foods*."

Is there a word to shorten this sentence?
Can I say , "I consume less sugar and salty foods *but fatty foods, otherwise?*

Answer (score 4):

I would further suggest that the word "sugar" be modified to "sugary," since I would doubt that you consume straight sugar.  It seems more likely that you're talking about the properties of the foods you consume.

In that case, the correct word to use is "fewer" (for foods, which are countable) and not "less" (used for non-countable things, like sugar).

I'm wondering why you chose the word "consume" instead of "eat." In conversation, "eat" would be more appropriate. My preference would also be to use it in writing (my cardinal rule, as a writer, is "keep it simple, keep it direct.").

I'd go for this: "I eat fewer sugary and salty foods than fatty foods."

Or: "I eat more fatty foods than sugary or salty foods."  This puts more stress on what you eat more of, than the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

I would see no problem with this:

> "I consume less sugar and salty foods but more fatty foods."